# Geometric Picture of z'(x, y(x))

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, multivalued-functions

When using the multivariable chain rule to compute $dz/dt$ of something with the form $z = f(x(t), y(t))$, the geometry involves moving from a number line ($t$) to a plane ($x$, $y$) to a new number line ($z$).  The equation $z = f(x(t), y(t))$ itself can be viewed as a progression of position vectors, or perhaps points to avoid later confusion, from the $t$ line to the $xy$ plane, to the $z$ line.  These are shown as red points below.  Similarly, $dz/dt$ can be viewed as a progression of tiny vectors stemming from these points, shown as relatively large purple arrows, but with the understanding that they're actually arbitrarily small.  The dependencies are shown in the tree structure on the right.

[image]

How does this geometric picture change in the alternative case of computing $dz/dx$ of $z = f(x, y(x))$, the following tree structure?

[image]

One bizarre facet of this latter case is that its formula, $dz/dx = ∂z/∂x + (∂z/∂y)(dy/dx)$ reveals in clear terms that $dz/dx$ and $∂z/∂x$ aren't the same thing; the total change in $z$ with respect to $x$ isn't the same as the partial change in $z$ with respect to $x$.

My hypothesis is that the axis of the intermediate $xy$ plane in this case is replaced by something other than an orthogonal axis.  The English clause "y is a function of x" or "y depends on x" sounds a lot like "y is influenced by x" or "y is partially determined by x," which aren't too unlike "a component of y points in the x direction."  Consider a plane starting with standard basis vectors $î$ and $ĵ$ that is then transformed by $\left[\begin{array}{l}1&\sqrt{2}/2\\0&\sqrt{2}/2\end{array}\right]$.  The transformed bases aren't orthogonal to each other anymore.  Viewed in light of our original basis, we could say that a component of $y$ now points in the $x$ direction, which is very reminiscent of our multivariable calculus situation.  This also shows promise for an analogy to the inequality of $dz/dx$ and $∂z/∂x$, as the basis vector that spans this plane's x-axis wouldn't be the full story of the $x$ components of the purple vectors.  So a red point and purple vector would start on an $x$ number line and move to a $y$ number line, but from $z$'s perspective, its input wouldn't (in general) look like a Cartesian $xy$ plane, but a modified $xy$ plane, where the x-axis remains in place, but the y-axis is rotated, sheered, etc., perhaps even twisted in some non-linear way.  It would stand to reason that iff $y$ is a linear function of $x$, the y-axis would be straight, and tools of linear algebra could be applied to shed new geometric insight into the problem.

Am I on the right track for thinking about the geometric picture of z(x, y(x)) and z'(x, y(x)), and if so, how can this be drawn out in a bit more detail?

Comment: $z$ is a composite function.In your second case, it's a single variable function. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} z$ doesn't make sense because z is a single variable function of $x$. The outside function $f$ is a two variable function. Given a composite function $z := f(x,g(x))$ where the outside function is $f(x,y)$ with inside function $y = g(x)$, the chain rule should be written (for any chain rule):derivative of the composition function = derivative outside function * derivative inside function$\frac{d}{dx}z = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f\frac{d}{dx}g$

Comment: In other words what I'm saying is that when you start comparing $\frac{d}{dx}z$ with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}z$ I'm saying that you have a notation problem. We have to clearly distinguish which is the composition function (z), and which is the outside function (f). These are two completely different functions over two different domain sets. The chain rule always has on the left hand side the composition function. and on the right hand side, the outside and inside functions. You are overloading $z$ for both the composition and the outside function,which ok sometimes but can be confusing too

Comment: Let's just look at your first tree diagram on the right for a second. It works, yet it also doesn't work because it's a little bit misleading. $z$ is a single variable function of $t$, and shouldn't have any lines connecting it to $x$ or $y$. $z$ should have a single line straight to $t$ and thats it. $f$ should have lines to $x$ and $y$ and that's it. I see what you are saying though. Varying $t$ will vary $x$ and $y$, because $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$, which since $x$ and $y$ are now varying, the output of $f$ will vary

Comment: The chain rule says that the direct variation of the composition (z is a single variable function - so how z varies with t) is related to the product of other variations of other functions (the outside and inside). As a side note, if you want to view $z = f(x, g(x))$ where $x$ is also a function, then $x$ has to be the output of the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) $id(x)$. Because if I say $x = 7$ and I also want $x$ to be an output of a function - then if I input $7$ into this function (the identity function) I have to get back 7

Comment: Isn't my notation for the second case the same as in this Khan Academy video, with Ψ replaced with z?  https://youtu.be/iEpqcdaJNTQ?t=113

Comment: It is, but he is technically wrong too (I like Khan academy - I've used it before to help me learn). If $\Psi$ is the outside function, a function of $x$ and $y$, then a $\frac{d}{dx}$ of $\Psi$ doesn't make any sense because it isn't single variable. $\Psi(x,y)$ is very very different from (which he fails to explain) the function $\Psi(x,g(x))$. $\Psi$ is the outside function, while $\Psi(x,g(x))$ is a composition, and therefore should be given a different name. All compositions should be given a different name. He should have either written on the left hand side of the equation

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,g(x))$ or called the composition a new name like Fred $:= \Psi(x, g(x))$ and have written $\frac{d}{dx}\text{Fred}$

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) If you look at the pictures on the right hand side. $g$ is composed with $f$. $g$, the outside function, is very different than $g\circ f$ because the domain of this composition is very different from the domain of $g$, or the domain of $f$ (though in the pictures - in this particular instance, the domain of $g\circ f$ is the same as the domain of $f$ -  but just in this instance)

Comment: So he's overloading a symbol as well. But in his mind, he knows what he's doing. To us however, we can't read his mind so using the symbol $\Psi$ over and over again leads to confusion (also his first equality before the equation - he's saying the the _output_ of $\Psi$ is equal to the _output_ of the composition function. But the two functions themselves are _not_ the same, just their outputs over their respective domains). So when you are comparing $\frac{d}{dx}z$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}z$, I'm saying these are two different functions being overloaded with $z$. It's like comparing

Comment: $d/dx f$ and $d/dx g$ when these are two random function. The chain rule shows how their derivatives are related. Their derivatives are related because the functions themselves, although different, are being put together to form a new composite function. So we should expect the derivative of the composite function to be related to the derivatives of the functions which were put together to make it in the first place